# Text not centring despite style from stylesheet

Tags: react-native, format, react-navigation

I'm trying to make a basic tab application with React Navigation and so I have three pages with plain text. They centre vertically but not horizontally on the tabs. This is using alignContent and justifyContent in conjunction with each other (which has worked for me in the past).

At first I suspected the flex was only flexing vertically and so I applied a contrasting colour. However it seems to span the tab. I have also tried textAlign, but neither cases seem to work.

This is an example of one of the screens:

```
export class ExampleScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Example!</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

And here is the StyleSheet:

```
export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
        alignContent: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
})
```

There are no error messages. However I would expect the text to centre horizontally but all I get is this:

[image: Simulator View]

Comment: you mean the text on the screen or in your tab?

Comment: Yeah, I mean the text on the screen.

Comment: try add AlignItems: 'center' in container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text is not horizontally center because Text is taking full width of the screen,
you need to center content inside Text

```
<Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Example!</Text>
```